# Flink: Jar file contains no main class

Tags: java, maven, apache-flink

When trying to execute a Flink job, I have this error message :

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Neither a 'Main-Class', nor a 'program-class' entry was found in the jar file.
```

Although in my pom, I declare the main class as:

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Main-Class>com.package.Main</Main-Class>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Can someone show me what I have missed ?

Thank you

Comment: How are you running the job? Which command?

Comment: Did you double check the jar file that is does contain the manifest files as well as your main class?

Answer (score 11):

It seems like an error on the `mvn package`. Have you tried the following command?

```
./bin/flink run -c your.main.class flinkprogram.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to declare the main class with the following entry in `pom.xml`:

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
   <configuration>
     <archive>
       <manifest>
         <mainClass>com.package.Main</mainClass>
       </manifest>
     </archive>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in eclipse/windows the issue could be not specifying the main class during the package of jar `<File->export->jar>`

[image: Eclipse-export-jar-main-class]